# Is A2.onDestroy(), A1.onRestart() order guranteed when moving back in Back Stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, back-stack

Wondering could somebody help with following?
Lets say I got task with following back stack: A0->A1->A2 where A2 is a topmost Activity. Wondering if I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP during calling A0 is there any guaranty that A2.onDestroy() -> A1.onDestroy() -> A0.onRestart() order will be called? Or Android could neglect order and do something like A0.onRestart()... -> A2.onDestory() -> A1.onDestroy() in order to show UI quickly?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should not rely on these calls to happen in any specific order. In general there is no guarantee about when `onDestroy()` will be called.

Comment: Ok, but it could be difficult to do graceful shutdown in case activities is depended between them self. I think then in my case I would better come up with fragment, I think I would get better control of back stack then.